# On Error GoTo for empty folder results in error

Tags: vba, loops, error-handling

I have a Macro which should go through subfolders of a folder and extract information from each of the Excel-sheets.
Unfortunately my code halts when there is an empty folder. I would like to catch that error and make the Macro skip that file.
I therefore tried to catch the error with "On Error GoTo FirstFunction" and redirecting it to the beginning of the loop.

But it just ignores my instruction and stops while throwing an error.

Here you see the relevant part of my code, I also added some remarks to the relevant lines:

```
For Each Folder In SUBFOLDER
FirstFunction:
        FolderName = Folder.name
        'MsgBox FolderName
                
            FoundFolder = Folder.name
            
            o = 0
            
            For z = 2 To k + 1
            
            If FoundFolder = Workbooks(Stamm).Sheets("Einzelwerte").Cells(4, z).Value Then
            o = o + 1
            
            End If
            
            Next z
            
            If o = 0 Then
           
            On Error GoTo FirstFunction 'is supposed to catch my error and to open the next folder
                                
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=strOrdner & FoundFolder & "\" & Quelldatei, Local:=True 'this is the line which is responsible for the error
```

I would be very happy if one of you could help me!

Comment: You never hit next so it's looping on the same value if you hit an error.

Comment: Instead of using On Error, why not check if the file exists before trying to open it?

Comment: I'd suggest that you include the whole code